# Powerquery to get data from Web Api using JSON

Tags: json, api, powerquery

I have been trying to get data using JSON for my Excel sheet. My code is below:

```
`let

#"apiUrl" = "https://www.goldapi.io/api/price/",

#"options" = [Headers=[#"x-access-token" = "goldapi-33urttkxxnt3tr-io", #"Content-Type"="application/json"]],

#"result" = Web.Contents(#"apiUrl", #"options")
in
#"result"`
```

I get the following error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://www.goldapi.io/api/price/latest' (400): Bad Request

What am I missing here? I have tried to follow all instructions that the website gave me to access the content.

[image: Website instructions]

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `/api/prices` is valid request?

I tried `https://www.goldapi.io/api/XAU/USD` and works fine.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your answer. I was not trying the correct link!